# SMB share mounted on Kubernetes but not content is visible (files or directories)

Tags: kubernetes, samba, smb, cifs

I have SMB share on windows which I'm trying to mount on Kubernetes as a persistent volume. I used this cifs plugin https://github.com/fstab/cifs and mounted the share on the pod. In the running pod when do a "ls" in the share folder I don't see any of the share content but I'm able to cd into the directories and also cat the files inside the share. The paths are valid but browsing through the content is not working.

I use the pod yaml provided below :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
   - name: busybox
   image: busybox
 command:
   - sleep
   - "3600"
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
volumeMounts:
- name: test
  mountPath: /data
volumes:
 - name: test
flexVolume:
  driver: "fstab/cifs"
  fsType: "cifs"
  secretRef:
    name: "cifs-secret"
  options:
    networkPath: "//server/share"
    mountOptions: "dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,noperm"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need to set up the correct permission for the folder using `dir_mode=0755` and `file_mode=0755`:

```
sudo mount -t cifs credentials=<credentials-files>,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755 //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/share
```

You can visit this page for more [info](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/).

Comment: Thank you it worked , but I'm doing the same thing onto a Kubernetes pod which is not working. I have update the question with the details , do you know anything about it ?

Comment: @j-vander   Do you have any clue about this ?

Comment: Sorry, I just have checked your [link](https://github.com/fstab/cifs) and they suggest to use another mountoptions have you tried them?

Comment: I’m exactly how they gave in the example. 
mountOptions: "dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,noperm".